# how to get textbox value from one php to another php

Tags: php

Currently I am working on php project. 
I tried to bring textbox value, which is

```
$password = $_POST['password']
```

from Forgotpassword.php to Thank-You.php file.

A lot of people advised me to put include('Forgotpassword.php') on Thank-You.php
but when I put include('Forgotpassword.php') on Thank-You.php, whole form from forgotpassword.php was showed on Thank-You.php. I just want to retrieve only textbox value on Forgotpassword.php.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try with session? Or else are you submitting a form? Please attach your code.

Comment: Check it out, it will help you - http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: This scares me in so many ways. From @tadman: WARNING: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern development framework like Laravel comes with a robust authentication system built-in.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done it by using session, in your Forgotpassword.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$data=$_POST['key'];
$_SESSION["variable"] = $data;
?>
```

And in your thankyou.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$data=$_SESSION["variable"];
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Forgotpassword.php:**

```
<form method="post" action="Thank-You.php">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Thank-You.php:**

```
<?php $password = $_POST['password'];
```